# What is <% used for in Basic?

Tags: asp-classic

I am maintaining some legacy Visual Basic ASP code and I keep seeing `<% ...code here...  %>` and I do not understand what this is used for. It seems to be some sort of blocking method but I cannot be sure and Google has been of no help because it is an odd search string. I realize this is a very "basic" question but any quick answer would be great.

Comment: Are you talking about Active Server Pages using VBScript?

Comment: I didn't know it was an ASP thing. See my comment on the answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic reading and not about programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<% %>` tags are not part of ***[Visual Basic Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)***, they is part of ASP.

They are called [ASP Code Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524929.aspx).

Also, you're more than likely working with [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) which is a different language from [BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC).

Comment: Here's the link for classic ASP (not to be confused with ASP.NET): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524929.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have no idea why people down voted me on this. I tried to figure this out on my own and wouldn't have posted a question if I hadn't tired on my own. I don't know ASP or VB at ALL. I am a php developer. I have never used ASP before this.

Comment: @BrandonBearden Essentially, they are almost the same thing as `<?php ... ?>`